# API version range in an Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm curious about what is the sense in setting both target and minimal supported API version when starting a new Android Studio project. I mean, if I set that minimal API is, say, 8, then I won't be able to use features from 22 (which could be my target), because it would break compatibility with API 8.

Comment: You can design your application using things like support libraries, resource modifiers, or exclusive features for certain API's. You may want to support back to something like 14 (just as an example), but wouldn't want to go past that as the functionality of your application would be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct. By setting target API to 8 you can't use any features added after, but specifying minimum API is just a guarantee that you application *will work* on such devices. You don't guarantee that it provide all features on such devices, nor minimum API level restricts what features it could use when running on later versions of OS.

Look at PE history - all win32 executable files are compatible with MSDOS, but all they say after executing is just "This is not a MSDOS program.". Similar to this, it is your decision what features you provide on which OS you support.

Answer (score 1):

> if I set that minimal API is, say, 8, then I won't be able to use
>   features from 22

You can use API level >= 8 features in application, but you have to check OS version of the device first, see following code, that's how you can maintain compatibility

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            //use features of API 3.0
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1){
            //use features of API 3.1
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
            //use features of API 3.2
}else{

// and so on....
}
```

Other then code, use can use resource folders on the basis of API level, like:

```
values-v11
values-v12
values-14
....
```

and

```
drawable-v11
drawable-v12
drawable-14
....
```